# How was the Skylab Rescue mission supposed to return 5 astronauts?

Tags: spacecraft-development, skylab

> In addition to the three manned missions, there was a rescue mission on standby that had a crew of two, but could take five back down.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab#Manned_missions

*How does one fit 5 astronauts in an Apollo command module?*  [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3162/26446) suggests a second row of seats for such a flight.  But where would the second row be placed?  In the lower equipment bay, perhaps?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Seats were installed in the lower equipment bay, instead of some of the usual storage lockers. A [Skylab rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab_Rescue) mission would take a few days at most, so the usual luxuries for a 2-week Apollo mission (like being able to go to the lower equipment bay for a little personal-hygiene privacy) could be foregone. The extra seats were mounted in the reverse direction from the main crew couches:

[image]

The rescue CSM had the usual Apollo service module (although, as with the other Skylab CSMs, th[e SPS tankage was reduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module#Modifications_for_Saturn_IB_missions) because it didn't need to make the large lunar-orbital-insertion and Earth-return maneuvers, and additional RCS fuel was carried for redundancy):

[image]

Comment: One point that I always thought was interesting is that the shock absorbers on the upper seats had to be modified to have less travel. Apparently it would have been a rough landing.